# Nginx " X-Frame-Options" set to two values

Tags: http, nginx, iframe, x-frame-options

I added this to my config:
    `add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://167.235.117.189" always;`. But Chrome says that there are two "X-Frame-Options" set. I searched with grep in my entire `/etc/nginx` directory but it only found the one I set. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does your server actually return? Check the raw response! (For example using `curl -D - https://yourwebsite.example.com`)

Comment: @CherryDT Both headers are present in the response.

Comment: What is the second one?

Comment: First: X-Frame-Options: deny
Second: X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://167.235.117.189

Comment: What type of content are you serving? Probably you are proxying another server like PHP or node.js. Is it possible that your backend application already adds the other header?

Comment: It is not setup as a proxy. It is directly accessing the php files

Comment: That means it's still kind of like a proxy for the PHP backend (via fastcgi). My point was it doesn't deliver static files itself, it calls PHP to run backend code and probably your PHP code adds that header.

Comment: Ok. Thank u for the explainstion. As u can see I solved the issue by telling fastcgi to hide this header. Have a great day @CherryDT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this: `fastcgi_hide_header X-Frame-Options;` to my route config

Answer (score 0):

Different browser may treat this differently. ALLOW-FROM has limited support outside IE. I would suggest to use the Content-Security-Policy header instead. Set the value to "frame-ancestors 'self' 167.235.117.189" if your current X-Frame-Options values are SAMEORIGIN and the ip. When the frame-ancestors directive is present X-Frame-Options will be ignored and you can allow both sources.